# Indexable US Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a map of the US with each state showing a count of "items".  When a user clicks the state they are then brought to another page (for that state) - like a drill down.  So far this is pretty simple.  However, I want to do this in a way that is indexable by Google and other search engines.  Is there a way to do that with Google Maps API?  Other ways to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you base your map on KML, [Google will be able to index it](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/01/get-more-traffic-to-your-maps-api-site.html) (or at least were indexing the KML).  A [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) with references to your "state" pages will let the search engine spider them without following your dynamic links.

Comment: While the sitemap will let google know about the pages won't not having links to them from my home page hurt their ranking?

Comment: I would would say adding links to them from your home page will help their ranking.  If they have useful content, they will appear high in the ratings, if they don't they won't.  There is nothing stopping you from having real links from your home page also.

Comment: Understood - but from a site design standpoint I'm trying to replace an ugly list of states with a nice map - so having both doesn't help me aesthetically.  What I was hoping for was a way to basically "load" the html links and have them render as the map.  E.g. the user sees the map but google bot sees the <a> tags.